# 英語が残っている：通報したという事

Tags: バグ, 完了, 英語

ロックをかけてもらうために自分の質問を通報した後、通報を覗くと英語が残っていました。
[image: You already have a pending flag on this question,This is the flag you currently have raised※英語以外は通報前と同じ日本語のままでした]

Comment: [Retract Flag](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/91489718?reviewed=no&q=Retract%20flag)と[You already…](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/91489709?reviewed=no&q=You%20already%20have%20a%20pending%20flag%20on%20this%20question)をとりあえず翻訳(レビューはまだですが)しときました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Sun-Solar-Arrowさんの翻訳](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/91489709?tags=q2286)をレビュー済みにしておきました。

Comment: [This is the flag…](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/91489712?q=This%20is%20the%20flag%20you%20currently%20have%20raised)はまだでしたので翻訳を急いでしました。そして、(これはどうでもいいのですが)ユーザー名はs`o`nではなくs`u`nです

Comment: 確認しました！ありがとうございます！